# How can I multiply and divide integers without bigger intermediate types?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, division, multiplication

Currently, I'm developing some fuzzy logic stuff in C# and want to achieve this in a generic way. For simplicity, I can use `float`, `double` and `decimal` to process an interval [0, 1], but for performance, it would be better to use integers. Some thoughts about symmetry also led to the decision to omit the highest value in unsigned and the lowest value in signed integers. The lowest, non-omitted value maps to 0 and the highest, non-omitted value maps to 1. The omitted value is normalized to the next non-omitted value.

Now, I want to implement some compund calculations in the form of:

```
byte f(byte p1, byte p2, byte p3, byte p4)
{
    return (p1 * p2) / (p3 * p4);
}
```

where the byte values are interpreted as the [0, 1] interval mentioned above. This means `p1 * p2 < p1` and `p1 * p2 < p2` as opposed to numbers greater than 1, where this is not valid, e. g. `2 * 3 = 6`, but `0.1 * 0.2 = 0.02`.

Additionally, a problem is: `p1 * p2` and `p3 * p4` may exceed the range of the type `byte`. The result of the whole formula may not exceed this range, but the overflow would still occur in one or both parts. Of course, I can just cast to `ushort` and in the end back to `byte`, but for an `ulong` I wouldn't have this possibility without further effort and I don't want to stick to 32 bits. On the other hand, if I `return (p1 / p3) * (p2 / p4)`, I decrease the type escalation, but might run into a result of `0`, where the actual result is non-zero.

So I thought of somehow simultaneously "shrinking" both products step by step until I have the result in the [0, 1] interpretation. I don't need an exact value, a heuristic with an error less than 3 integer values off the correct value would be sufficient, and for an `ulong` an even higher error would certainly be OK.

So far, I have tried to convert the input to a `decimal`/`float`/`double` in the interval [0, 1] and calculated it. But this is completely counterproductive regarding performance. I read stuff about [division algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm), but I couldn't find the one I saw once in class. It was about calculating quotient and remainder simultaneously, with an accumulator. I tried to reconstruct and extend it for factorized parts of the division with corrections, but this breaks, where inidivisibility occurs and I get a too big error. I also made some notes and calculated some integer examples manually, trying to factor out, cancel out, split sums and such fancy derivation stuff, but nothing led to a satisfying result or steps for an algorithm.

Is there a

- performant way
- to multiply/divide signed (and unsigned) integers as above
- interpreted as interval [0, 1]
- without type promotion

?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you right, maybe I'm off with this, but aren't you optimizing too much? I mean, actual processors have registers for WORD, DWORD and if it's x64 QWORD, so any arithmetic will be executed in one cycle independent if it's a byte, a short, an integer or even a long.

Comment: Are you SURE that multiplication and division is faster using integers? As isn't multiplication/division using integers that are in the interval [0,1] rather trivial considering they can only be 0 or 1?  and if you exclude the highest value, isn't the answer always 0 (or NaN)?  Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes, it is, if he's micro optimizing so much must be targeting some ARM device or similar, and the float operations take some cycles more than integer arithmetic on those platforms.

Comment: @Gusman: I agree, but I am looking especially for a solution to the wider integer I still need in the middle of the calculation and the [0, 1] interpretation.

Comment: @RobertMcKee: I'm not saying "I only ever want to use `ulong`", I want to enable someone, who uses my class, to use whatever numeric primitive type he/she wants to. And I want to cover endge cases.

Comment: _MulDiv_, "fractional arithmetic". My short take: No way "without carry" (or "machine support"). Follow-on question: is there a way to make do with a) one _base type_ value, one bit, or even one _base type_ value _and_ one bit of carry?

Comment: @greybeard: This sounds like what I need. Up to 2 "carry-base-types" would be OK, so any of your alternatives would suffice.

Comment: In C, C++, C# and probably many other language intermediate result are promoted (generally to `int`) but your function `f` would give a truncated result while it would be rounded result with floating points. Assuming that you call `f(80, 7, 6, 5)` you would get a result of `17` but you might expect `18` as otherwise error would accumulate faster...

Comment: I don't really understand the relation between C# and ARM device code optimization. If you want to optimized code for a specific device, then you have to write low level assembler code.

Comment: @Phil1970: Sure, that's what I wanted to avoid and I can live with a little error. And of course, I won't code C# on µC, but it is far easier for me to test the actual algorithm first in a C# or Java program until I really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as summarised: No.
You need to state (and rank) your overall goals explicitly (e.g., is *symmetry* more or less important than *performance*?). Your chances of getting a helpful answer improve with succinctly stating them in the question.
While I think [Phil1970's `you can ignore scaling for … division`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877993/3789665) overly optimistic, multiplication is enough of a problem: If you don't generate partial results bigger (twice as big) as your "base type", you are stuck with multiplying parts of your operands and piecing the result together.
For ideas about piecing together "larger" results: [AVR's Fractional Multiply](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_FMULSU.html).
Regarding `…in signed integers. The lowest, non-omitted value maps to 0…`, I expect that you will find, e.g., *excess -32767/32768-coded fractions* even harder to handle than two's complement ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not careful, you will lost more time doing conversions that it would have take with regular operations.

That being said, an alternative that might make some sense would be to map value between 0 and 128 included (or 0 and 32768 if you want more precision) so that all value are essentially stored multiplied by `128`.

So if you have `(0.5 * 0.75) / (0.125 * 0.25)` the stored values for each of those numbers would be 64, 96, 16 and 32 respectively. If you do those computation using `ushort` you would have `(64 * 96) / (16 * 32) = 6144 / 512 = 12`. This would give a result of `12 / 128 = 0.09375`.

By the way, you can ignore scaling for addition, substraction and division. For multiplication, you would do the multiplication as usual and then divide by 128. So for `0.5 * 0.75` you would have `64 * 96 / 128 = 48` which correspond to `48 / 128 = 0.375` as expected.

The code can be optimized for the platform particularly if the platform is more efficient with narrow numbers. And if necessary, rounding could be added to operation.

By the way since the scaling if a power of 2, you can use bit shifting for scaling. You might prefer to use 256 instead of 128 particularly if you don't have one cycle bit shifting but then you need larger width to handle some operations.

But you might be able to do some optimization if the most significant bit is not set for example so that you would only use larger width when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your try, I'm familiar with shifting, bit operations, multiplication, division and type promotion (I changed the last term in the original question). This is unfortunately not an answer to my question. I'm not converting - if I start with bytes, I process bytes and I get bytes back. This is my goal. Symmetry and avoiding wasted space makes me use 254 as denominator and maximum value. I also want to avoid having a `short` or even a bigger type intermediately. Platform specific optimization is not the point here, too. Division by 128 in your example is scaling, too. I'll have a look.

Comment: If you don't use a power of 2, then operation like multiplication will definitively be harder to implement...

Comment: By the way, a table might be used for division if using an array and replacing division by multiplication is an option. Assuming that you use a scaling of 128, then a division by 3 would essentially be a multiplication by 43 (128 / 3) and then throwing the last byte. For example, if you have 99 / 3, you could do 99 * 43 = 4257 then 4257 / 128 = 33.25.